# Make YouTube video visible to only users in a particular domain

Tags: youtube, privacy, security, sharing, access-control

I'd like to make a YouTube video that is visible only to users in a particular domain (e.g., anyone registered as *@x.com).  Is there a way to do that?

The only settings I can see are Private, Unlisted, and Public.  I can't find a way to mark it so everyone whose account is associated with a particular domain (x.com) can view it. Is that supported?

Answer (score 1):

I don't Think so. What you can do is mark your video as unlisted and then share the link with the people you want to see the video. However, What you want can be done in vimeo, check there website for details.